# Change the color of a background (specific section)

Tags: html, css

I'm making a static site. I have a white background in my body tag set. I want to know if there is any way to set the background color behind everything on my site for just a specific area. I basically want to have a background color for the images on my website. I have researched online and found the `z-index` and I was not sure how to exactly use it. Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: background color for images.. are these images transparent?

Comment: No, not the actual pictures behind the pictures i want to change the background of the website

Comment: using css you can use `background-color` in the `body` tag or any other tag (`div` or `section` etc..)

Comment: you can also set `background-color` for html tag as well, but I didn't understand your question at all.  )))

maybe there is a live example what you do and what you need?

Comment: yes, you need to show us some html for us to understand or look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/b7v3tgaf/

Comment: So i basically have three images on my website. I want to put a square background around them. I tried making a div with a grey square then setting it behind the images. All it did was push the images down. Is there a way to force the div to the back?

Comment: There are ways to force positioning using css `position`. In your case, before going there, how about using `border` for the images like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ko2wzah9/1/

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Provide some CSS / HTML. You can set the opacity on the img and wrap it in a div with a background - [like this example](http://jsbin.com/colufo/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment here:

> So i basically have three images on my website. I want to put a square background around them. I tried making a div with a grey square then setting it behind the images. All it did was push the images down. Is there a way to force the div to the back?

The best way to do so would be to apply a border to your images:

```
img {
  border:5px solid #yourColor;
}
```

Bear in mind, this will "still" push the images down, so if you're *really* wanting to keep them in the same location, you could give each image a wrapper and then set the position of the image absolute, compared to the relative wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px; // Set this to the opposite of your border size
  border:5px solid #yourColor;
}
```